# Create custom model class with python

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I have an example class as follows:

```
class MLP(nn.Module):
    # Declare a layer with model parameters. Here, we declare two fully
    # connected layers
    def __init__(self):
        # Call the constructor of the `MLP` parent class `Module` to perform
        # the necessary initialization. In this way, other function arguments
        # can also be specified during class instantiation, such as the model
        # parameters, `params` (to be described later)
        super().__init__()
        self.hidden = nn.Linear(20, 256)  # Hidden layer
        self.out = nn.Linear(256, 10)  # Output layer

    # Define the forward propagation of the model, that is, how to return the
    # required model output based on the input `X`
    def forward(self, X):
        # Note here we use the funtional version of ReLU defined in the
        # nn.functional module.
        return self.out(torch.relu(self.hidden(X)))
```

Calling the class is like this:
`net = MLP() net(X)`

Now, I need to create a similar class and function for a model with 4 layers:

Layers  Configuration   Activation Function
fully connected input size 128, output size 64  ReLU
fully connected input size 64, output size 32   ReLU
dropout probability 0.5 -
fully connected input size 32, output size 1    Sigmoid

I need to pass the following assertion:

```
model = Net()

assert model.fc1.in_features == 128
assert model.fc1.out_features == 64
assert model.fc2.in_features == 64
assert model.fc2.out_features == 32
assert model.fc3.in_features == 32
assert model.fc3.out_features == 1

x = torch.rand(2, 128)
output = model.forward(x)
assert output.shape == (2, 1), "Net() is wrong!"
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
                
        
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(128, 64)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(64, 32)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=0.5)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(32, 1)
        

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.fc3(torch.sigmoid(self.dropout(self.fc2(torch.relu(self.fc1(torch.relu(X)))))))
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (2x20 and 128x64)
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: Posting layers again due to poor formatting:

Comment: 1.   fully connected,            input size 128, output size 64, activation function:       ReLU

Comment: 2. fully connected ,           input size 64, output size 32, activation function:          ReLU

Comment: 3. dropout ,                       probability      0.5      ,                   -

Comment: 4. fully connected           input size 32, output size 1 , activation function:         Sigmoid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a capital `X` in the `forward` method, while the function expects lowercase `x`. You must have a tensor with shape (2, 20) assigned to variable capital `X`.